# python - check if all items in an iteration have equal properties

Tags: python, ftplib

I'm kind of new to python, and I'm writing a script that logs into a ftp server to get a list of files and then checks if all files in the same folder have the same size, but I can't find a way to compare the sizes while the folder path is the same, this is where I've got so far:

```
import ftputil

server = 'xxxxxx'
user = 'xxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxx'
root_folder = 'xxxxxx'

ftp = ftputil.FTPHost(server, user, password)
recursive = ftp.walk(root_folder, topdown=True, onerror=None)
for root_folder, subdir, files in recursive:
    for name in files:
        file_path = ftp.path.join(root_folder)
        file_size = ftp.stat(ftp.path.join(root_folder, name))[6]
        print(file_path, file_size)
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to compare sizes of the files in the same directory?

Comment: you could loop through each file in the directory and store the sizes and names in a list, then when done scaning that directory you could compare the sizes in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the bulk of your code works.  I assume you either want True of False, and when you find the first difference, you want to stop the iteration. For example:

```
same_size = None
common_size = False   # initialise

recursive = ftp.walk(root_folder, topdown=True, onerror=None)
for root_folder, subdir, files in recursive:
    for name in files:
        file_path = ftp.path.join(root_folder)
        file_size = ftp.stat(ftp.path.join(root_folder, name))[6]
        print(file_path, file_size)

        if common_size is None:      # execute on first file
            common_size = file_size
        elif common_size == file_size:
            same_size = True
        else
            same_size = False
            break
```

You need to decide what to do if there is only one file there.

Answer (score 0):

Start iterating with empty value, set it at first item and compare to this value afterwards.

```
expected_size = None
for root_folder, subdir, files in recursive:
    for name in files:
        file_size = ftp.stat(ftp.path.join(root_folder, name))[6]
        if expected_size is None:
            expected_size = file_size
        if expected_size != file_size:
            return True
    return False
```